# Обложка из mp3 файла

Tags: c++, c++builder, mp3

Здравствуйте. Есть ли возможность стандартными методами Builder'a, без подключения каких-либо библиотек, вытащить из mp3 файла обложку альбома и вывести ее на форме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вытащить из mp3 дополнительную информацию, нужно знать формат этой информации. Скорее всего речь о [ID3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_%28%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%29). Ну и уметь пользоваться функциями чтения файла. Т.е. обойтись без сторонних библиотек вполне возможно, нужно лишь реализовать чтение метаданных.

Comment: А где можно найти примеры подобного?

Comment: @Мечтатель подобного чего?

Comment: примеры работы с ID3 в Borland'е, любые примеры, которые помогут осуществить подобную задачу новичку.